# Calculation in function

Tags: c

```
double cost_factor(int num_of_sections, int num_of_students) {
    double cost;
    cost = 35 * num_of_sections / num_of_students;
    printf("Cost = %.2lf\n", cost);
    return cost;

}
```

No matter what i enter for num_of_sections and num_of_students, I get a return value of 1.00.
If I enter 11 (num_of_sections) and 364 (num_of_students), I get 1.00, althought it should be 1.06.  Can anyone identify their error?

Answer (score 9):

You are doing math with integers. So you will get integer values back.

```
const = 35 * num_of_sections / num_of_students
```

will give you an int even though `cost` is a double because all the components are `ints`.

You will want to typecast the value to get a `double` out

```
cont = 35.0 * (double)num_of_sections /  (double)num_of_students;
```

Mind you that is over kill, it is enough to promote one value in the equasion to a double.

```
cont = 35.0 * num_of_sections / num_of_students;
```

C will then automatically promote the other values for you.

Comment: There is no reason to change the types of your inputs. You should use the type that makes the most sense to describe the input. You just need to promote the values when doing calculations.

Comment: Isn't the last part slightly wrong. Because of precedence num of selection / num_of_students happens first and produces an int which is latter converted to double. So it would do integer division and lose the fractional part?

Comment: @fayyazkl - Why would it do division first? They have the same operator precedence so they are evaluated left to right.

Comment: Yeah my bad. I was applying standard math precedence subconsciously i.e. division before multiplication. They have same precedence and hence operate left to right.

Comment: @fayyazkl - Standard math precedence states that Division and Multiplication have the same precedence and should be evaluated left to right.

Comment: Speaking as someone with maths degree, "standard math precedence" actually doesn't allow you to write `a / b / c` at all, so its rules are different from C. `a * b / c` has the same meaning whether you group it right or left, provided that division is the inverse of multiplication and multiplication is commutative. Integer division isn't a "standard math" operation :-)

Comment: @fayyazkl: really that should be spelled BO{DM}{AS}, it could just as well be BOMDSA.

Answer (score 3):

Dividing two integers returns an integer, with the fractional part removed.  Try this instead:

```
cost = 35.0 * num_of_sections / num_of_students;
```

`35.0` is a double literal instead of an integer literal.  This will cause the expression `35.0 * num_of_sections` to be evaluated as `double * double` (the `int` is converted to a `double` before the calculation) and then the division will also take place using two doubles.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was to promote `num_of_students` and `num_of_sections` to double so that `cost` can be correctly calculated.

```
double cost(double num_of_students, double num_of_sections)
```

Comment: No I didn't unless you want to see what I'm passing.

Answer (score 1):

Look at all your operations: they all involve only integers, so C does integer math. The quickest way to solve is to make `35` a `double`, which will cause the promotion to `double` of the other operands (if any of the operands in an operation is `double` the other is promoted).

So you can do either:

```
cost = ((double)35) * num_of_sections / num_of_students;
```

or, better,

```
cost = 35. * num_of_sections / num_of_students;
```

(some prefer `35.0`, but the dot at the end of `35.` is enough to specify that it's a `double` literal; `35` alone, instead, is intended as an `int` literal)

Comment: Bit of a nit-pick on this but I'd put the 0 after the 35. just to make it clear what you mean.

Comment: @zellio: I preferred the "just the dot" form because often you find that form used (especially in my code `:)` ), so if he's learning C it can be useful to know that also that syntax is valid.